# How to create a route dynamically in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to create 2 routes dynamically for the same url but it says

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

for this code:

```
[:get, :options].each do |x|
  send(x), '/my_url' do
    # ....
  end
 end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '/my_url' is a parameter of the get function, so it needs to be a parameter of the send function:

```
send(x, '/my_url') do
    # ...
end
```